# Find if the value of any controls, inside a form, changes

Tags: angularjs

**Requirement** - I've a form with multiple controls (input, radio button and select). Now I need to dynamically capture values for each of these controls in a textarea control.

**Question** -  Is there any way I could fire an event whenever value changes for these controls? I know how ng-model or ng-change works individually for each control, but I need at Form level.

at "script.js" file, this didn't work (as this function can not be fired dynamically):-

```
$scope.ProjectTaskSchedules.Description = getSchedularDescription();

    var getSchedularDescription = function()
    {
        if ($scope.ProjectTaskSchedules.SchedulerType.SchedulerTypeName == 'One Time') {
            $scope.ProjectTaskSchedules.Description = 'abc...'
        };
        if ($scope.ProjectTaskSchedules.SchedulerType.SchedulerTypeName == 'Recurring') {
            $scope.ProjectTaskSchedules.Description = 'xyz...'
        };

    };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far?

Comment: Why would you need an event? Just display what the value of each element is, using angular expressions. The expressions will be reevaluated each time the model changes.

Comment: @JB Nizet:- whenever control's value (inside the form) changes, I need to do some if-else check on these current values and then create the final string value ($scope.ProjectTaskSchedules.Description) which is actually bound to the "textarea".

Comment: well u could use $watch on your textarea where u enter the values of all other inputs so when smth is changed the textarea changes and the $watch starts working where you could do ur if else thingy and update the textarea

Comment: Then use the expression `computeFormDescription()` in the view. The function will be called automatically by angular every time something changes in the scope, and will create a new description based on the new model.

Comment: Try http://plnkr.co/edit/b2FOog8Fp8yoQ4DaK6r9?p=preview for a simple example. Enter values in the two input boxes, and not how the description changes automatically. Try entering "John" in the first input box.

Comment: @JBNizet - That's freaking amazing. What I already knew was this - {{controller's scope variable}} and this gets bound continuously with modal. But what I didn't know was the awesome stuff you threw on me - {{controller's scope function}}. Nizet, that's smooth. Thanks.